# How do I prevent pandas from writing a new column when I save to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I wrote this code just so show the example that I'm having. I need to save the data I have to a csv then reopen it later but when I reload the data into a pandas dataframe from csv it now has an extra unnamed column at the front that I don't want and it's messing up my data when I try to do .drop_duplicates() because each row now has its own number and every I reopen it from a csv it will have a new row of number at the front, just making everything worse. How do I make it so it doesn't have this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns=list('ABCD'))

df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df.head())
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

print(df1.head())
```

Comment: `df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Its the dataframe index. You can turn that off with

```
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

The docs are the first stop to learn the different options you have when writing. [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

While reading, you can prevent columns with empty rows like:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv").dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was super easy. I needed to do

df.to_csv('data.csv', index= False)